# Bernoulli's Inequality for x = -2

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For Bernoulli's Inequality:

$(1+x)^n \geq 1 + nx$   $  (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})$ where $x \geq -1$

Why is it not true that Bernoulli's Inequality holds for x = -2?

Comment: Which version of Bernoulli's inequality are you referring to? Please give more details in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Bernoulli's inequality I'm familiar with is: when $r\ge1$ is a *real number*, then if $x\ge-1$ then $(1+x)^r \ge 1+rx$.

First, note that this statement does not say that the inequality is false for other values of $x$ (it doesn't make any claim at all about $x=-2$, for example). That's mistaking asserting the inverse of the given implication.

For most values of $r$ (irrational values, for example), it doesn't make sense to write down $a^r$ when $a$ is negative. That's the most natural reason for the restriction $x\ge-1$, or else $1+x$ will be negative.

For positive integer values of $r$, one can look at $(1+x)^r$ for $x<-1$, and it definitely holds for $x=-2$ as can be proved directly. It seems to me that it holds for all $x\ge-2$, in fact, while for any $x<-2$ there will be some large enough $r$ for which it fails.